# Getting rows from DB in WordPress using $wpdb causes critical error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a table in my database called `attendants` and a page called `results.php` that will have data on all the rows returned.

Essentially I'm trying to do two things:

- Get count of rows in table.
- For each row in table, input its data in a `.card`

However, after commenting out lines, I've found that this line causes a critical error on my page:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM attendants");
```

Unsure why? I thought it was the get_results() function, but [according to the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/), it seems like the correct way to retrieve rows?

I also don't think the data is being retrieved as when trying to echo a value, it returns nothing.

**results.php**

```html
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM attendants");
$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($results);
echo $results; // returns "Array"
?>

<div class="resultsPage">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card__header">
   <!-- trying to print number of rows in attendants table -->
   <!-- i.e there are 7 rows in this table, so $number_of_results should return 7 -->
   <h4>Total respondants: <?php echo $number_of_results; ?></h4>
  </div>
 </div>


 <?php
 foreach($results as $result){ 
  $first_name  = $result["first_name"];
  $last_name   = $result["last_name"];?>
  <div class="card">
   <div class="card__copy">
    <p><span class="card__data">Full name:</span> <?php echo $first_name+" "+$last_name; ?></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, if you have access to phpMyAdmin, can you check your table Attendants is not prefixed by wordpress prefix ?

If it is, you should change your query by :

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}attendants");
```

If your table is created by a plugin or in the wordpress way, quite sure it will be wordpress prefixed.

Secondly, you use mysqli_num_rows functions which is the php way with a result returned with a wordpress way (abstraction of which type of database used behind).

As you didn't provided the type of results returned by get_results, it's an array of objects.

So, to get count of results returned, you should use :

```
$number_of_results = count($results);
```

As it's an object in the loop, you should use notation :

```
$result->first_name
```

instead of array notation.

Hope it helps